# Ubuntu 12.04 unable to putty or sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sudo

One particular user is unable to putty or use sudo. The user can login using the VMware console but still cannot sudo. User can change password using passwd user no problem. When the user tries to sudo gets "Sorry, Try again" three times.
Other users can putty and sudo. This user is a member of the same groups as the other users. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the file `/etc/sudoers`. That's where the permission to use sudo are set.

If it's still doesn't work, post the current configuration of the sudoers file and the current groups of the user in question.

Comment: #
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

Comment: # User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Members of the Ubuntu xxxxxx Users group may gain root privileges
%Ubuntu_xxxxxx_Users ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: Here is the sudoers file, sorry don't know how to format correctly here

Comment: current groups  -  groups aventine  
aventine : aventine adm dialout cdrom plugdev sambashare lpadmin admin